# Retrieving the custom attribute value defined by my client

Tags: c#, .net, custom-attributes

I was trying to play with custom attributes of c#.

And as a part of this, consider this scenario: I have my client class which gives me a string to hash and specifies the hashing algorithm using custom attributes.

I was able to come up to this but stuck up when how to retrieve the custom attribute value.

```
class HashAlgorithmAttribute : Attribute
{
    private string hashAlgorithm;

    public HashAlgorithmAttribute(string hashChoice)
    {
        this.hashAlgorithm= hashChoice;
    }
}

[HashAlgorithm("XTEA")]
class ClientClass
{
    public static string GetstringToBeHashed()
    {
        return "testString";
    }
}

class ServerClass
{
    public void GetHashingAlgorithm()
    {
        var stringToBeHashed = ClientClass.GetstringToBeHashed();

        ///object[] hashingMethod = typeof(HashAlgorithm).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(HashAlgorithm), false);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using mocked up example of your attribute class:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = true)]
sealed class HashAlgorithmAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string algorithm;

    public HashAlgorithmAttribute(string algorithm)
    {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    public string Algorithm
    {
        get { return algorithm; }
    }
}
```

And test class:

```
[HashAlgorithm("XTEA")]
class Test
{

}
```

To get value:

```
var attribute = typeof(Test).GetCustomAttributes(true)
     .FirstOrDefault(a => a.GetType() == typeof(HashAlgorithmAttribute));
var algorithm = "";

if (attribute != null)
{
    algorithm = ((HashAlgorithmAttribute)attribute).Algorithm;
}

Console.WriteLine(algorithm); //XTEA
```